# Debug webpage in Chrome Android App from desktop localhost with port forwarding

Tags: android, debugging, google-chrome

I'm following https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#reverse-port-forwarding.

My android device shows up in Chrome on my desktop at `chrome://inspect`.

I have a server running on my desktop. `http://localhost:3000` loads fine in Chrome on my desktop.

I tried clicking the port forwarding button and putting in `8080` and `localhost:3000` then navigating to `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:3000` in Chrome on Android, but I only got 'could not connect to server' messages. It won't accept `80` and `localhost:3000` as valid options.

What do I need to do to be able to view the server on my desktop from my android device?

(Btw if you know the answer to this maybe you can also help with [Chrome Remote Debugging a local site on a Virtual Machine with port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375681/chrome-remote-debugging-a-local-site-on-a-virtual-machine-with-port-forwarding))

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there was a bug in Chrome that [only allowed ports greater than 5000](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322245). See also [this possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849535/how-can-i-view-a-website-running-in-localhost-on-machine-in-chrome-browser).

Comment: this is a valid answer